# How to make the conversion of a project with managed beans to one with CDI Beans?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, managed-bean

I tried to convert managed Beans ***ManagedBeans*** to ***CDIBeans*** simply by including ***@Named*** and ***@XxxScoped*** from *javax.entreprise.context* package. Along with the two JAR files ***cdi-api-1.1-PRD.jar javax.inject-1.jar***. But it seem to be not as simple as that.

> 1. I wanted to know why?
> 2. Why isn't the above mentioned process
>      working?

Shouldn't CDI beans support functionalities of managed beans? Am I totally missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least add empty beans.xml file to META-INF/ or WEB-INF/ in your archive.
There are other things you may need to do but that depends on your runtime environment.
[There's a nice config example for Tomcat](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/configuring-cdi-with-tomcat-example)